# Why does word sorting with Perl appear to be wrong?

Tags: perl

My question in Perl is:
Perl Script which will read the text (no punctuation or numbers) and print out a sorted list of words and the number of 
times each occurs in the text.
My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@names = qw(My name is Ashok Rao and I am the son of Shreesha Rao and Shailaja Rao);
join(',',@names);
my %count;
foreach (@names)
{
 if (exists $count{$_}) 
 {
  $count{$_}++;
 } 
 else
 {    
  $count{$_} = 1;
 }
}
my @order = sort(@names);
print "The words after sorting are:\n";
print "@order\n";
print "The number of times each word occurring in the text is: \n";
foreach (keys %count) 
{
 print "$_ \t = $count{$_}\n";
}
```

The Output is:

```
The words after sorting are:
Ashok I My Rao Rao Rao Shailaja Shreesha am and and is name of son the
The number of times each word occurring in the text is:
the = 1
son = 1
of = 1
name = 1
Ashok = 1
Shailaja = 1
is = 1
Rao = 3
am = 1
My = 1
I = 1
and = 2
Shreesha = 1
```

But I think the SORTING part output is wrong. Word occurrence part output is correct. Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong how? perl makes a distinction between lower and upper case.

Comment: Oh.You are right. I did not notice that. Thanks

Comment: According to `ASCII Code` the sorting sequence is correct. How do you want them to get sorted?

Comment: Yes. The sorting sequence is correct. I did not notice that perl makes a distinction between lower and upper case. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: While it is normally good practice to check whether a hash key exists before using it, `++` and `+=` are special cases.  `$hash{key}++` will automatically create `$hash{key}` and set it to one if it doesn't exist.  So your first loop can be just: `$count{$_}++ foreach (@names);`

Comment: Oh.Yes.Single line statement worked instead of such lengthy loop. Thank you so much Sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perl makes a distinction between lower and upper case.
You can use the `uc` and `lc` functions to convert a string to upper or lower case.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that your sort is occurring by ASCII character code, rather than by word order.  This means that all the uppercase words will proceed all the lowercase ones.  To solve this, just specify your own comparison when calling the sort function:

```
my @order = sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} @names;
```

By making each side of the comparison lowercase, this enables a correct alphabetical ordering.